# Sending messages fail when bulding a simle chat room

Tags: php

I try the tutorial on net to build chat room.

First I create a database in MYSQL called chatroom and buld a datasheet called chat with three columns:chtime, nick, words.

Then I write four PHP files, login.php, main.php, display.php, speak.php but encounting problem about display and speak. My speak doesn't work and I just pop up a new window without any words.

I don't know where is the problem?

I have tried to fix it several days but in vain. Where is my error?

The following is my code:

Login.php
http://codepad.org/WIfr3quz

Main.php
http://codepad.org/b9pXuNl0

Display.php
http://codepad.org/o7pf5G57

Speak.php
http://codepad.org/wFDEMrNk

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 25 on Display.php according to the debug

Comment: But my speak.php does'nt work, and I don't know when the Display.php's error after checking the line.

Comment: Display your errors and tell us what it says.   We cant help you debug on your local host without error reporting turned on.

Comment: The speak.php just pop up a new window without any word after I press the speak button, and I find that it doesn't do "INSERT ...." to the database and I don't know why it doesn't do that.

Comment: See my answer below.  You will never get into the if block because `$words` is not defined.   Either do it like I suggest or define `$words` before the if block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAKE SURE YOU READ UP ON SQL INJECTION

Where is `$words` defined?

```
    if ($words){
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'ChatRoom');
        $time = date('Y-m-d-a:i:s');
        $str = "INSERT INTO chat(chtime,nick,words) values('$time','$nick','$words')" ;
        mysqli_query($str,$link);
        mysqli_close($link);
}
```

You should so something to define these.  Not sure what else to tell you without seeing what kind of errors show up.. This is where i would start though..  make the block look something like

```
if(isset($_POST['words']))
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'ChatRoom');
        $time = date('Y-m-d-a:i:s');
            $nick = 'NickName';//However you would get the nick for the user
            $words = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['words']);
        $str = "INSERT INTO chat(chtime,nick,words) values('$time','$nick','$words')" ;
        mysqli_query($str,$link);
        mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: I have tried $_POST['words'] before,but after that the column to be input will disappear.

Comment: Huh?  I dont get what you mean by the column to be input will disappear?

Comment: My comment in the $nick var needs to be removed and put in some string there.  Or fill in $nick with who is logged in to the chat, see updated code

Comment: I put error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1); in the if's block and it doesn't pop up any error, so it's right?

Comment: But it still pupout a new blank window without any words, I think I have set target = " _self"?

Comment: Yes, I have use its var.But I use setcookie to set nick before, why shoud I define it again?

Answer (score 1):

Change the code in speak.php to:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Speak</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<?php 
    if ($words){
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'ChatRoom');
        $time = date('Y-m-d-a:i:s');
        $nick = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['nick']);
        $words = $link->real_escape_string($_POST['words']);
        $str = "INSERT INTO chat(chtime,nick,words) values('$time','$nick','$words')" ;
        mysqli_query($str,$link);
        mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
<form action = "Speak.php" method = "post" target = " _self"> 
<input type = "text" name = "nick"> 
<input type = "text" name = "words">
<input type = "submit" value = "Speak"> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Using [real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) prevents SQL code injection.
The values sent by a POST form are stored in $_POST.

Comment: Will never get into this block because if($words) will always be false.  It would need to be $_POST['words']